# as for 'replace' usage, does it support to replace the placeholder with value in place (I mean "over-write"))?

Tags: karate

I need to upload a file to the server side, however, before doing that I need to replace a placeholder in the file with a dynamic value.  does it support to get the placeholder replaced in place dynamically?

I noticed that I can replace the placeholder with ease using the 'replace' keyword.  The following is my script:

Given path 'common/upload'
    And multipart fields read('classpath:mainFlow/labresultUpload.json')

```
* def filename = 'PKU.A22backup'
* def someString = read('PKU.A22backup')
* print someString
* replace someString
  |token|value|
  |labsampleid|'123456'|
* print someString

* multipart file file = { read: "#(filename)", filename: "#(filename)"}

When method post
Then status 200
* def result = response[0].result
```

However, I need to replace the placeholder in place (here, I mean over-write) dynamically and then upload the file to the server side.

Comment: ok, I have marked the answers as ”accepted"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the option to supply a value instead of the file-name: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-file

```
* multipart file file = { value: "#(someString)", filename: "#(filename)" }
```

Comment: it works now, thank you so much for your quick reply.